# How can the CreatedDate of a record not be the date it was created?

Tags: contracts

I got this strange case - were a contract record was created at 20/12/2016, but it shows in createdBy old date 15/12/2015.
The correct created date shown in the lastmodifiedDate.

According to my code the record was supposed to be created at 20/12/2016, this is shown also in the history, and it's also seems according to the contract running number (not sure if it's reliable...), still can't figure how it got createdBy with old date, as I don't have any code that manipulate the createdBy field.

Any idea how it can happen?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Custom Object from a Managed Package, or yours? Is there some kind of automatic merge? The record was almost certainly created on the 15th in 2015, we can see from your screenshot it was however last modified on the 20th of 2016. The auto-number increment also seems to corroborate that it was indeed created on the 15th.

Comment: Hi. This is standard object- Contract, and both fields are also standard. Indeed the createBy shows 15th, but the history shows 20th.  + in the 20th exactly at this time there was process that supposed to create this record.

Comment: That is odd because `CreatedDate` isn't a field that's writable, nor do I believe the Field History Tracking is.

Comment: +1 - a good question and I reworded your OP title to make it more useful to future searchers

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the issue.
It got this createdDate via clone function. In the clone function there is boolean that determine if the copied record will get the same createdBy/createdDate from the source.